# Multiprocessing in Python using Process, how to limit the number of processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'd like to run multiple processes concurrently, but using Process I cannot limit the number of processes at a time, so that my computer becomes unusable for anything else.
In my problem I have to run the main_function for all of the data in my_dataset. Here is a short sample of my code, is it possible to limit the number of processes at a time?

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def my_function(my_dataset):
    processes = []

    for data in my_dataset:
        transformed_data = transform(data)
        p = Process(target=main_function, args=(data, transformed_data))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Yes. Look at using a pool of worker processes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#module-multiprocessing.pool

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the multiprocessing's Pool
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
names = ["Joe", "James", "Jimmy"] * 10
    
    
def print_name(name):
    print(f"Got Name: {name}")
    
    
def runner():
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(print_name, names)

if __name__== "__main__":            
    runner()
```

Comment: add `if __name__== "__main__":` before `runner()` orelse his PC will crash

Comment: Depends where you're running it, I ran it on Jupyter notebook. but will add it for clarity

Comment: Just for completeness, the check is needed for Windows and OSX